# Как достать из массива все значения price

Tags: php, массивы

То есть нужно получить 2,3,300,10000,2,455

```html
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => 
            [sentences] => [{"index":"0","price":"2","amount":"5"},{"index":"1","price":"3","amount":"100"},{"index":"2","price":"300","amount":"5"},{"index":"3","price":"100000","amount":"1000"}]
            [id] => 825
            [userid] => 1
            [auction_id] => 2949
            [bid] => 100305.0000
            [date] => 2021-02-26 13:29:52
            [proxy] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => 
            [sentences] => [{"index":"0","price":"2","amount":"5"},{"index":"1","price":"455","amount":"100"}]
            [id] => 826
            [userid] => 187
            [auction_id] => 2949
            [bid] => 457.0000
            [date] => 2021-02-26 12:56:31
            [proxy] => 0
        )

)

foreach($query_result->sentences as $index => $arSentence) {

    echo $arSentence['price'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $sentences = array_column($query_result, 'sentences');

    $prices = [];

    foreach($sentences as $item) {
        $prices = array_merge($prices, array_column($item, 'price'));
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но только пришлось чуть переделать.

$sentences = array_column($query_result, 'sentences');

$prices = [];
                                
foreach($sentences as $item => $arItem) {
    $arItem = json_decode($arItem, true);
    $prices = array_merge($prices, array_column($arItem, 'price'));
}

Answer (score 0):

```html
$sentences = array_column($query_result, 'sentences');

 $prices = [];
                                
foreach($sentences as $item => $arItem) {
  $arItem = json_decode($arItem, true);
  $prices = array_merge($prices, array_column($arItem, 'price'));
}
```